# VBA not equal <> If condition runs its code although its actually equal to it and should not run

Tags: excel, vba

`If TextBox5.Value = Workbooks("Excel Stock System.xlsm").Worksheets("DataNews_Events").Cells(i, 6) <> "Yes" Then`

The content of the Cell is actually "Yes" and yet it runs the code. I can't figure out why. I checked with a messagebox if it reads the correct cell and if there are any spaces or anything else and there arent. Its exactly it.
Its not supposed to run the IF condition if it actually is equal to "Yes". How is this possible, why does it happen and how can i work around this weirdness ?
Help

Comment: Remove `TextBox5.Value =`?

Comment: you are asking if the result of `TextBox5.Value = Workbooks("Excel Stock System.xlsm").Worksheets("DataNews_Events").Cells(i, 6)` does not equal `yes` and `True` or `False` will never equal `yes`

Comment: Use one operator per logical block. If you have multiple conditions use `Or` / `And`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you have two conditions, the first one is the following:

```
TextBox5.Value = Workbooks("Excel Stock 
 System.xlsm").Worksheets("DataNews_Events").Cells(i, 6)
```

The last condition is evaluated to either TRUE or FALSE, so the next condition evaluated by your program is going to be something like this

```
TRUE  <> "Yes"  ----> FALSE
FALSE <> "Yes"  ----> FALSE
```

In either case, both conditions are evaluated to FALSE because boolean values are different from the text.

If you want to compare just the value of the cell with the value "Yes", it would be necessary to change the conditions and remove the text box part. Something like this, I think, will be useful

```
Workbooks("Excel Stock 
 System.xlsm").Worksheets("DataNews_Events").Cells(i, 6) <> "Yes"
```

In either scenario, if you want to compare if the textbox and the cell value are equal to the values "Yes" I would recommend the following modification to your code

```
Dim oRng as Range
Dim i    as Long

Set oRng = Workbooks("Excel Stock System.xlsm").Worksheets("DataNews_Events").Cells(i, 6)
If oRng.value = "Yes" and TextBox5.Value = "Yes" Then
    'Do something
Else
    'Do other thing
End if
```

Hope will be useful.

Comment: Thank you , how could I overlook something so obvious haha , I guess next time before I post I should just get some sleep first.

Comment: You're welcome, as I learned through the years when we are in a hurry or with a short time to solve a problem we start overthinking and imagine overcomplicated scenarios but, most of the time, the answer is quite simple. So it's a good practice to check and make sure the basics are ok and then start with more complicated things.